# Why is my design works fine only with small screen sizes?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I have followed this great tutorial to the letter to design modern UI using `FontAwsome.Sharp`

[RJ Code Advance Modern UI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AsJJl7Bhvc)

I have two issues , First in the form design mode everything is as it supposed to be but in debugging the controls are missed up I do not know why !

This is my form in design mode :
[image]

And This is how it looks in debugging :
[[image]][]

The form has two docked panels and some `IconButtons` , Here are current properties :

> panelMenu `Panel`

```
Dock Left
Size 231, 687
```

> `IconButtons`

```
Size 231, 60
Dock Top
FlatStyle Flat
ImageAlign MiddleLeft
TextAlign MiddleLeft
TextImageRelation ImageBeforeText
```

Second issue , Even if the design is right this method :
`ActivateButton(object senderBtn, Color color)`
Does not do anything at all it should change the `BackColor` of the `IconButtons` , Move icon And show side small border for the buttons .
I compared the code with the source no problems with it

```
 public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    // Fields
    private IconButton currentBtn;
    private Panel leftBorderBtn;
    private Form currentChildForm;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        leftBorderBtn = new Panel();
        leftBorderBtn.Size = new Size(7, 60);
        panelMenu.Controls.Add(leftBorderBtn);
       
    }
    private struct RGBColors
    {

        public static Color color1 = Color.FromArgb(172, 126, 241);
        public static Color color2 = Color.FromArgb(249, 118, 176);
        public static Color color3 = Color.FromArgb(253, 138, 114);
        public static Color color4 = Color.FromArgb(95, 77, 221);
        public static Color color5 = Color.FromArgb(249, 88, 155);
        public static Color color6 = Color.FromArgb(24, 161, 251);


    }
    // Methods
    private void ActivateButton(object senderBtn, Color color)
    {
      if (currentBtn != null)
        {
            DisableButton();
            currentBtn = (IconButton)senderBtn;
            currentBtn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(37,36,81);
            currentBtn.ForeColor = color;
            currentBtn.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            currentBtn.IconColor = color;
            currentBtn.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.TextBeforeImage;
            currentBtn.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            // Left Border Button
            leftBorderBtn.BackColor = color;
            leftBorderBtn.Location = new Point(0, currentBtn.Location.Y);
            leftBorderBtn.Visible = true;
            leftBorderBtn.BringToFront();

        }


    }

    // Disable Button
    private void DisableButton()
    {
        if (currentBtn != null)
        {
            currentBtn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(31, 30, 68);
            currentBtn.ForeColor = Color.Gainsboro;
            currentBtn.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            currentBtn.IconColor = Color.Gainsboro;
            currentBtn.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
            currentBtn.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        }
    }

    private void btnItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActivateButton(sender, RGBColors.color1);
        
    }
```

I am using visual studio 2015 .
Sorry for the long post but your help will be deeply appreciated.

Edit#1 : I have built the form and used it on a laptop and the design was OK the problem is with my current 43 Inches screen , Is there a way to fit all screens ?

Comment: What's your screen DPI?

Comment: It is a 43 Inch TV screen 1920 x 1080 ( Full HD).

Comment: Okay, but I asked you about your DPI setting

Comment: I don`t know how to get it , Sorry .

Comment: But i have built the form and tested it on my laptop and the form was ok , But the method `ActivateButton` still do nothing .

Comment: You never set `currentBtn` to anything anywhere, what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: What about this ` ActivateButton(sender, RGBColors.color1);` ? And the same code works for the guy i do not see the problem in the code , would you fix it ?

Comment: What about it? You still aren't setting `currentBtn`. Use a debugger if you can't just read your own code.

Comment: Thank you so much , I knew the error , It was under my nose the whole time `if (senderBtn != null)` this is the fix in ActivateButton .

Comment: what about the screen size , Anchoring will fix this issue ?

Comment: Is there a way to automatically scale the form to fit any screen resolution ? need help guys.

Comment: You're setting size in absolutes, what you want is relative percentages, with a minimum absolute size.

Comment: Thanks for reply , Can you make a demo code ? , I didn’t use this way before . Thanks

Comment: I tried setting the form size to 80% of screen resolution the form resized correctly  but the controls still the same size the font getting smaller on large screen although the anchor and the dock properties are set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly but looks like you have the screen scale to 125% and not 100%.
It's possible? I had a similar problem with an app I made in a user pc, and was for this reason.

Comment: I figured it out by chance three days ago and was as you said 150% , Hoped you came earlier , But the bounty is yours :) Thanks